# Grab Parameters And Query in PHP

Tags: php, sql, parameters, query-string

I'm passing a string of parameter to my php code, but I don't know exactly what the parameters are. Let's say I pass in a string that contains

```
?&cName_1=fbe&cName_2=ege&cBirthday_1=r3rg&cBirthday_2=fev
```

I not only need to know what each parameter is but I also need the names and the birthdays to line up for my query.

I was trying the following code but that only works with one parameter at a time

```
$email = $_GET['email'];

foreach($_GET as $key => $value){
    $query = "INSERT INTO directory(cName, cBirthday, username) VALUES('$value', '$pBirthday', '$email')";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
}
```

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to do. Are you saying you will have parameters in your get request as Name_1, Name_2 ... Name_10 & Birthday_1, Birthday_2 ... Birthday_10 and you need to extract their values and pass them to a sql query with Name & Birthday of _1, _2 and so on till _10?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm trying to do!!

Comment: You are open to SQL injection attacks. Check [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Comment: This would be much easier if you passed a JSON construct (preferably via POST). Is that a possibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do some handy manipulation of PHP's request-based super globals (ie `$_GET` and `$_POST`) by using square brackets to denote array indices / keys.

For example, a query string like

```
?email=me@example.com&c[0][name]=fbe&c[0][birthday]=r3rg&c[1][name]=ege&c[1][birthday]=fev
```

results in the following `$_GET` structure

```
Array
(
    [email] => me@example.com
    [c] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => fbe
                    [birthday] => r3rg
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => ege
                    [birthday] => fev
                )

        )

)
```

To add further parameters, you just append

```
&c[n][name]=value&c[n][birthday]=value
```

where `n` is the next index.

---

This would be much easier to work with in your code, especially with a prepared statement

```
// Make MySQLi report errors as exceptions
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$email = $_GET['email'];
$stmt = $con->prepare(
        'INSERT INTO directory (cName, cBirthday, username) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $cName, $cBirthday, $email);
foreach ($_GET['c'] as $c) {
    $cName = $c['name'];
    $cBirthday = $c['birthday'];
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To get the values from the string you can do this :

```
<?php

    $string = "?&cName_1=fbe&cName_2=ege&cBirthday_1=r3rg&cBirthday_2=fev";
    $get = explode('&', $string ); // explode with and

    foreach ( $get as $key => $value) {
        $valn[ substr( $value, 0 , strpos( $value, '=' ) ) ] =  substr( $value, strpos( $value, '=' ) + 1 ) ;
    }
    // access your query param

    $cName_1 = $valn['cName_1'];
    $cName_2 = $valn['cName_2'];
    $cBirthday_1 = $valn['cBirthday_1'];
    $cBirthday_2 = $valn['cBirthday_2'];

?>
```